# Loop without freezing the program?

Tags: c#

I have a seemingly simple task I am trying to perform but just cannot get my program to work.

This is in C# and what it does is sends a ping to my server and return if it responds or not. The issue I am having is that I want it to wait for X seconds before trying again so there is not a ping flood to my server. If I make the program wait using Thread.Sleep it freezes the GUI. This is a problem as the GUI tells the user if the server is up or not. I have also tried the background worker to no avail. Any ideas?

My Code:

```
  Ping ping = new Ping();
        string x = "go";

        while (x == "go")
        {



            try
            {
                lblS1checking.Text = "Checking...";
                PingReply reply = ping.Send("SERVER NAME", 2000);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    lblS1check.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                    lblS1check.Text = "UP";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblS1check.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    lblS1check.Text = "DOWN";
                }

            }
            catch (PingException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed!");

            }
            lblS1checking.Text = "Done.";

            //PROGRAM NEEDS TO SLEEP HERE FOR 30 SECONDS BEFORE TRYING AGAIN. GUI SHOULD NOT FREEZE DURING THIS TIME.

        }
```

Comment: Use Background Worker

Comment: Use a Timer on your form to execute the ping every x seconds

Comment: Background worker is one of the solutions, but am not sure how it didn't work for you, can you please post your code that you tried using background worker?

Comment: I would suggest using the new Task<T> async stuff in C# 5 rather than the older background worker as it's easier to use and more up to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use timer as shown below :-

```
 public static void Main()
   {
        // Create a timer with 30 seconds interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
   }
```

and when timer expires below method will be called!

```
   private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      try
                {
                    lblS1checking.Text = "Checking...";
                    PingReply reply = ping.Send("SERVER NAME", 2000);
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        lblS1check.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                        lblS1check.Text = "UP";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblS1check.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        lblS1check.Text = "DOWN";
                    }

                }
                catch (PingException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed!");

                }
                lblS1checking.Text = "Done.";
            }
    }
```

Comment: This will freeze UI for up to `2 sec` (in case of ping timeout) every `30 sec`. Solution is to wrap event handler into `Task.Run(() => { ... });` and invoke UI calls (it looks like winforms, so to example, `this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => lblS1Check.Text = "DOWN"));`)

Comment: HI @Neel, if need to ping multiple ip address at the same time what should i do for it .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Ping.SendAsync 
Here the code from the MSDN:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace Examples.System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingTest
{
    public class PingExample
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException ("Ping needs a host or IP Address.");

            string who = args[0];
            AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent (false);

            Ping pingSender = new Ping ();

            // When the PingCompleted event is raised, 
            // the PingCompletedCallback method is called.
            pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler (PingCompletedCallback);

            // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted. 
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);

            // Wait 12 seconds for a reply. 
            int timeout = 12000;

            // Set options for transmission: 
            // The data can go through 64 gateways or routers 
            // before it is destroyed, and the data packet 
            // cannot be fragmented.
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions (64, true);

            Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", options.Ttl);
            Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", options.DontFragment);

            // Send the ping asynchronously. 
            // Use the waiter as the user token. 
            // When the callback completes, it can wake up this thread.
            pingSender.SendAsync(who, timeout, buffer, options, waiter);

            // Prevent this example application from ending. 
            // A real application should do something useful 
            // when possible.
            waiter.WaitOne ();
            Console.WriteLine ("Ping example completed.");
        }

        private static void PingCompletedCallback (object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // If the operation was canceled, display a message to the user. 
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Ping canceled.");

                // Let the main thread resume.  
                // UserToken is the AutoResetEvent object that the main thread  
                // is waiting for.
                ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set ();
            }

            // If an error occurred, display the exception to the user. 
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Ping failed:");
                Console.WriteLine (e.Error.ToString ());

                // Let the main thread resume. 
                ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
            }

            PingReply reply = e.Reply;

            DisplayReply (reply);

            // Let the main thread resume.
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
        }

        public static void DisplayReply (PingReply reply)
        {
            if (reply == null)
                return;

            Console.WriteLine ("ping status: {0}", reply.Status);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
                Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
                Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
                Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
                Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```